# check if point is in the same height as other point

Tags: java

Got project that make points on the Cartesian coordinate system, and stuck on something.
Everything works fine but in the isUnder() and at isRight() field I got problem 
when I enter point with the same y (for isUnder()) or the same x (for isRight()), 
This is work for my degree, got some limitation about them..

I need both of them to

1. **use the other method ( for isUnder() use isAbove() and for isRight() use isLeft() )**
2. **without using other operation and without using the property of the Point.**

What can I do ?

here is the relevant code:

```
public class Point
{

   private int _x;
   private int _y;
   
   /**
    * creates a new Point object.
    * @parm _x is the coordinates of a point on the x axis.
    * @parm _y is the coordinates of the point on the y axis.
    */
   public Point(int x, int y){
       _x=x;
       _y=y;
   }
   /** check if two points are in the same coordinates.
    * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
    * @return true if the points are in the same coordinates.
    */
   public boolean equals (Point other){
       if(_x==other._x && _y==other._y){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
   
   /** check if one point is above another.
    * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
    * @return true if the point is above the point we compare to.
    */
   public boolean isAbove (Point other){
       if(_y>other._y){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
   
   /** check if one point is under another.
    * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
    * @return true if the point is under the point we compare to.
    */
   public boolean isUnder(Point other){
       if(isAbove(other)){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
   
   /** check if one point is left to another.
    * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
    * @return true if the point is left to the point we compare to.
    */
   public boolean isLeft(Point other){
       if(_x<other._x){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
   
   /** check if one point is right to another.
    * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
    * @return true if the point is right to the point we compare to.
    */
   public boolean isRight(Point other){
       if(!isLeft(other)){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: what if the points have the same x coordinates, from what I understand you are assuming that if `isLeft` is false, then `isRight` has to be true?

Comment: that is my question.. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify a lot your code and get rid of the unnecessary if conditions.
The issues you are getting when you are comparing two `Point`s with the same `y` (for `isUnder()`) or the same `x` (for `isRight()`) are explained as follows:

- `isUnder()`: you delegate this to `isAbove(other)`. In fact, you should have used `!isAbove(other)`, but even then you would get an issue, because `isAbove(other)` will return `false` if both `y` are the same and then `isUnder()` would return `true` because you are negating the value from `isAbove(other)`.
- `isRight()`: you deleagete this to `!isLeft(other)` and then again if both have the same `x`, `isLeft(other)` will return `false` and `isRight()` would return `true`, but that is also wrong.

To fix this you also need to check in `isUnder()` if `y` are the same and in `isRight()` if `x` are the same. Something as follows:

```java
public class Point
{

    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    /**
     * creates a new Point object.
     * @parm _x is the coordinates of a point on the x axis.
     * @parm _y is the coordinates of the point on the y axis.
     */
    public Point(int x, int y){
        _x=x;
        _y=y;
    }
    /** check if two points are in the same coordinates.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the points are in the same coordinates.
     */
    public boolean equals (Point other){
        return _x == other._x && _y == other._y;
    }

    /** check if one point is above another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is above the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isAbove(Point other){
        return _y > other._y;
    }

    /** check if one point is under another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is under the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isUnder(Point other){
        return !isAbove(other) && (_y != other._y);
    }

    /** check if one point is left to another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is left to the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isLeft(Point other){
        return _x < other._x;
    }

    /** check if one point is right to another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is right to the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isRight(Point other){
        return !isLeft(other) && (_x != other._x);
    }
}
```

---

Given that you are not supposed to use the properties to check this, then you could do the following:

```java
public class Point
{

    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    /**
     * creates a new Point object.
     * @parm _x is the coordinates of a point on the x axis.
     * @parm _y is the coordinates of the point on the y axis.
     */
    public Point(int x, int y){
        _x=x;
        _y=y;
    }
    /** check if two points are in the same coordinates.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the points are in the same coordinates.
     */
    public boolean equals (Point other){
        return _x == other._x && _y == other._y;
    }

    /** check if one point is above another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is above the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isAbove(Point other){
        return _y > other._y;
    }

    /** check if one point is under another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is under the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isUnder(Point other){
        return other.isAbove(this);
    }

    /** check if one point is left to another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is left to the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isLeft(Point other){
        return _x < other._x;
    }

    /** check if one point is right to another.
     * @parm other the point to compare to this point.
     * @return true if the point is right to the point we compare to.
     */
    public boolean isRight(Point other){
        return other.isLeft(this);
    }
}
```

This means you would basically check if `this` is under `other` by checking if `other` is above `this`. Similarly, you would check if `this` is at the right of `other` by checking if `other` is at the left of `this`.

Comment: first of all thx for answer and the fixes, can i check it without using the properties of the point ? (one of the question limitation)

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it ;)

Comment: thx this is working first of all , more limitation is not to use **this** in the course.. lol
 there is someting to swap the this to make it work ?

Comment: Ok, you are adding requirements as we go. Please don't do that. Include all the details in your first version of the question. But in that case, you have been assigned an impossible task. There is no magic in programming. Why shouldn't you be able to use `this`? I mean, do you know that `this` is just the keyword for the object in which you have called the method `isRight()` for example? If I can understand the restriction of not using the properties in those methods, I can't understand why you shouldn't be allowed to use a perfectly fine and legal Java keyword.

Comment: just got a responde from my profesor, i can use this.
thx for the helo everyone !! :)

Comment: Glad that we could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can return **null** when your coordinate(x or y) are same, and after check if it null.

```
   public Boolean isLeft(Point other){
       if(_x<other._x){
           return true;
       }
       else if(_x==other._x){
           return null;
       }
       else{
           return false;
       }
   }

   public boolean isRight(Point other){
       if(isLeft(other)==null) {
           return false;
       }
       return !isLeft(other);
   }
```

Comment: was try this, but dosent let me returrn null to a boolean type you know why?

Comment: the type must be Boolean (with a capital letter) and not boolean, because boolean is an iterator it cannot be null while Boolean is an object like any other.

Comment: ye but in the qustion details they want me to use boolean and not Boolean.. very restrict teacher

Answer (score 0):

Just swap `this` and `other`.

```java
public boolean isUnder(Point other) {
    return other.isAbove(this);
}
public boolean isRight(Point other) {
    return other.isLeft(this);
}
```

Comment: thx this is working first of all , more limitation  is not to use **this** in the course.. lol 
there is someting to swap the this to make it work  ?